# How to make thie RewriteRule sub-domain agnostic?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With help from [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) I have this nice RewriteRule working.

```
short.dev  redirects to longer.dev
short.com  redirects to longer.com
```

using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?short\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://longer.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I now need to extend this rule to make it sub-domain agnostic too - like:

```
www.short.dev redirects to www.longer.dev
www.short.com redirects to www.longer.com

es.short.dev redirects to es.longer.dev
es.short.com redirects to es.longer.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make first group as captured group and use it in back-reference later:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?short\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://%1longer.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: can you please check this once if you have time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339372/how-to-rewrite-url-by-htaccess-with-basic-parameters-in-core-php
Thankx