# How to rewrite URL by Htaccess with basic parameters in core PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello all i am having a issue with this URL rewrite.

**my current URL is like this**

> domain.com/professional?seo=ACCOUNTIFY-SERVICES-&-ADVISORS&id=3173

here the **page name professional** can be changed to any page like i will have the similer url with other page names.

**Desired URL**

> domain.com/professional/ACCOUNTIFY-SERVICES-&-ADVISORS/3173

**i know that i can do this by htaccess for sure**

here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

please suggest me the changes needs to be done here to achieve the desired url.
Thank you so much for any help.
i have been reading some answers here and if i find a solution i will post here.

Comment: `&` is delimiter for query parameters.. `seo=ACCOUNTIFY-SERVICES-&-ADVISORS&id=3173` is a strange query string because it has `&` in `seo` parameter as well.

Comment: i will replace that in the SEO parameter by string replace. the SEO paramenter can have anything i will use the replace special charectors . you can ignore that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)(?:.php)?\?seo=([^\s&]+)&cat=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)(?:.php)?\?seo=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L,NE]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?&seo=$2&cat=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?&seo=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: it works but then all the CSS gets missing , i think the probelm is with GET AND POST data .. css files get 404 error

Comment: To fix this css/js issue, you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: ok sure, after changing the css files link to absolute it works great thank you so much, but it works for only one page it works for professionals.php not for blog/post.php

domain.com/blog/post?seo=vacancy-for-company-secretary&cat=2&id=2717
does not convert this.

Comment: oh ok sure, Thankx for the help always. :)

Comment: # external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)(?:.php)?\?seo=([^\s&]+)&cat=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?&seo=$2&cat=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]

i added the above code to rewrite the below URL it gives me 404 error. ples check it once if you have time. no rush and thank for the help always you are hero
domain.com/blog/post?seo=vacancy-for-company-secretary&cat=2&id=2717

Comment: ok Thankx for your help sir, i am sorry to say it dosent work it gives me 404 error, but its fine i will read about the .htaccess error and find the solution.

Comment: ha ha ha, Thankx for the help. and yes it works awesome. i will give you credit in my projects. Thankx always.